# How to expand UICollectionView Cell on when selected without messing up the collection view

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, cell

Currently I have a my didselect to expand each of my cells like this:

```
@objc(collectionView:didSelectItemAtIndexPath:) func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print("selected")
    let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath)

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: ({


        cell?.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 331, height: 320)
       // cell?.superview?.bringSubview(toFront: cell!)

        }), completion: nil)

}
```

The issue I am running into is the cells start to overlap over each other instead of adjusting downwards to the large cell size. I want to be able to click on any cell, it expands to a the larger size while the other cells move down to account for this resizing. Clicking on a second cell would make the first cell smaller. How do i go about doing this? Its been a struggle!

Comment: pls halp.......

Answer (score 0):

You should call for reloadItems in didSelected and then resize item in sizeForItemAtIndexPath:

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

NSLog(@"when SELECTED");
__weak MainCollectionViewCell *cell = (MainCollectionViewCell*)[self.yourCollectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];

if (cell.isSelected) {
    NSArray *indexes = [[NSArray alloc] init];
    [indexes arrayByAddingObject:indexPath];
    [self.yourCollectionView reloadItemsAtIndexPaths:indexes];
 }
}

- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
              layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout
sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

NSLog(@"size for Item called");

CGSize size = self.view.frame.size;

__weak MainCollectionViewCell *cell = (MainCollectionViewCell*)[self.yourCollectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];

if (cell.isSelected) { 
    return CGSizeMake(size.width, size.height);
} else {
 // return your original item size
    return CGSizeMake(300, 300);
}
}
```